# How to debug memory leak in python with cherrypy and pytorch

Tags: python, docker, memory-leaks, pytorch, cherrypy

I have cherripy python app, which eats all my RAM eventually.
**How do I debug the memory leak?**

I have a `pytorch` model, and I wrapped it into `cherrypy` to provide simple rest-api for inference.

```py
cherrypy.tree.mount(MyServer(), '/')
cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_port': 8080,
    'server.socket_host': "0.0.0.0",
    'server.thread_pool': 30,
    'log.access_file': "access1.log",
    'log.screen': True
})
try:
    cherrypy.engine.start()
    cherrypy.engine.block()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    cherrypy.engine.stop()
```

Where `Myserver is`:

```py
class MyServer(object):
    @cherrypy.expose
    def index(self):
        return "healthy"

    @cherrypy.expose('/inference')
    def inference(self):
        cl = cherrypy.request.headers['Content-Length']
        rawbody = cherrypy.request.body.read(int(cl))
        body = json.loads(rawbody)

        result = doSomePyTorchStuff(body)

        return json.dumps(result)
```

Initially, the app takes around 800mb of ram, which mostly to pick up some binaries (pre-trained models) into the memory.
With every new request, the memory usage keeps growing, and after 2 days saw the app took full `14G` of memory on my GPU doing nothing!

I see the same result when running it on CPU instead of GPU. `23G` are consumed easily and even faster.
I do run my app in a docker container, but when running without it - the result is the same - memory is constantly consumed.

Can someone point me in the right direction?
At this moment I can't narrow down the problem, not even sure if it's because of `cherrypy` or because of `pytorch`, or because something else.

Comment: Are you doing inference with `torch.no_grad()`? Not that it should matter, but autograd generally has a huge "leakable" surface

Comment: Try dumping cprofile stats somewhere time to time. Or use py-spy. Or use some remote debugger like `PYTHONBREAKPOINT=pudb.remote.set_trace` to connect there and inspect what objects exist in the Python runtime.

Comment: You could also just take out that pytorch logic and run it a lot of times separately while measuring the memory growth.

Comment: @Jatentaki I do use `torch.no_grad()`. Didn't know that it can influence the leakage.

Comment: @webKnjaZ thanks, I'll try these.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your model loads every time when inference calls (or during instantiating server). Sometimes model loading is memory and time consuming, so if you do it rather often, you can face memory leak.

It's common practice to instantiate torch model once (e.g. in singleton) and then inference it multiple times (e.g. in `MyServer.inference`).